# Google Sheet Notifications: Email out text from specific cell/s if sheet edited

Tags: email, notifications, google-sheets

Is it possible to send a notification when a sheet is updated which references a particular cell?

The cell I want to reference, let's say C15, is static and contains text.

So when a form is submitted/the spreadsheet is updated, an email will arrive that says "VA spreadsheet updated: Your value-added was significantly lower/higher than average this month." Taking this text from cell C15.

Thanks

Tardy

Comment: Need few clarification:

Comment: 1) What do you mean by a sheet is updated which references a particular cell? Do you have a field in your form that asks for a reference to a cell? 2) Does the cell you refer to change each submission 3) the notification should go to the person submitting the form or to another specific person? A link to your spreadsheet or example would be useful.

Comment: Hi Jagannathan
Here is a link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xb-mUPRjalv0rfnWOR5jkHJOCfaS661q-5nwhmmynBw/edit?usp=sharing
1. When I submit the Google Form, I would like the contents of the third sheet, 'Update', to be sent out in an email (as text, if possible; but if this can't be done, in a link to the spreadsheet).
2. The cell location is static but the contents will update when the Form is submitted.
3. I would like an email to be sent only to my email address. But I am also the only person submitting the form, if that matters.
Hope that clarifies the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should take care of emailing you the details computed from the form.

```
/* Paste the below code in your spreadSheets Tools > ScriptEditor
Then setup trigger for on onFormSubmit in ScriptEditor
Resources > Current Project Triggers > Add New Triggers > from Spreadsheet > on Form Submit

Remember to change the "Your email ID here" to email ID you need the mail to send the email 
*/
    function emailMileage() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Update");

    var userEmail = "your Email ID here"
    var sendername = "Mileage App"
    var subject = "Your Mileage:";
      if(sheet != null){
       // This combines the values from three cells in update sheet with a space  
       var message = sheet.getRange(1,1,3,1).getValues().join(" ");

      } else {
        var message = "Unable to find update Sheet!" 
      }

      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: userEmail,
        name: sendername,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: message
      });



    }
```

Comment: Brilliant! Just tried it; worked a treat! 
Will try and get my head around the ScriptEditor now and see if I can do this on other projects. Thanks, Jagannathan.